# Made invisible sections in an image

Tags: objective-c, image, animation

I have two images, one upon the other and I want to delete the little section(finger) when I tap on the top image or swipe on it. In this "deleted" section the other image should be visible.

How to achieve this?

Comment: Convert your top image to RGBA array and set alpha component of that pixel to 0.

Comment: So essentially you're saying that anywhere you touch, swipe etc it will show through the the image underneath (almost like an eraser effect)?

Comment: Thanks for your answers, you brought me on the right way,  found this.

https://github.com/craighowarth/WipeAwayView

That is exactly what I want.

Answer (score 0):

I would use 3 images with transparencies, where one disappears when you tap. I think it's the easiest way to achieve what you want.